# Applying changes in list preference

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I have a list preference with two values and I want to update these two values from with values from another array.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     Resources resources = this.getResources();
     String languageData = prefs.getString("languageAlias", " ");
     String[] languageAlias = resources.getStringArray(R.array.languageAlias);
     String[] voiceData = resources.getStringArray(R.array.voiceData);

     int a = 0;
     for(a=0; a<languageAlias.length; a++){
     if(languageData.equals(languageAlias[a]))
     {
         //this is where I have problems
         prefs.edit().putString("voiceAlias", voiceData[2*a]);
         prefs.edit().commit();
         break;
     }
```

I have been able to get it working up until I have to use the puString command to make the change and commit. Also how do I specify which item in the list preference I want to change, as all I am required to pass to the putString function is a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

you need to add:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

Then instead of

```
prefs.edit().putString("voiceAlias", voiceData[2*a]);
prefs.edit().commit();
```

use

```
editor.putString("voiceAlias", voiceData[2*a]);
editor.commit();
```

The documentation on [edit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit%28%29) says:

> Create a new Editor for these preferences

This means that each time you call `prefs.edit()` it creates a new `Editor` object, so when you put string with `prefs.edit().putString(...)` and when you commit with `prefs.edit().commit()` you're referencing two new, different `Editor` objects.

I believe you can also do `prefs.edit().putString(...).commit()`, but I am not sure if that is possible.

Comment: This works but doesn't give me the result in the way I want it. I want to update both items. This updates just one

Comment: If you know you are only going to have two different things to add, then you can have one key named `voiceAlias` and another key with a different name. If you have an indefinite number of things to add to one... heading, per-say, then you should use an `sqlite` database, I believe. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write String arrays to your SharedPreferences. You need to change that. You can use

> putStringSet (String key, Set values)

but this is available only from API Level 11 onwards. So check that. Or you could convert your array into a single String or into a JSON String (an example I saw elsewhere)

Check out the link below.
[Is it possible to add an array or object to SharedPreferences on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3876680/1244489)

Comment: I read about the putStringSet function but my API level is too low

Comment: In that case I suggest you change it to some other format like JSON/XMLor just a plain String with some delimiter like "|". You can then load it and do a splitString to get the array back :)

Comment: Are you able to write a String directly into the Preferences? That kinda sounds questionable.

Comment: yes, I can write a string directly into the preference but it doesn't give the desired result

Comment: Why dont u try te suggestion I mentioned? It might work for you.