# Calling multiple activities in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

Can anyone tell me how to call the n number of activities from different pages using sharedPreference?

Comment: Question is unclear......Modify your questionnnn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save an array in your `SharedPreference`. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android) for that.

Your array can hold the names of your `Activities`. Like:

```
String activityNames[] = { "Activity1" , "Activity2" , "Activity3" };
```

Fetch this array from your `SharedPreference`, and then start the desired `Activity` using:

```
Class selected = Class.forName("learn.myandroidapp.hr." + activityNames[someIndex]);
Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,selected);
startActivity(selectedIntent);
```

I haven't given you the entire code, but the basic idea(which is more than sufficient,I believe). Feel free to enquire for more.