# Xamarin Forms How to make a draggable listview

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, draggable

Is it possible to create a listview with draggable list items using Xamarin forms?

I have found a reference to this achieved in android in the link below but I'm not sure how I would go about this in Xamarin.Forms, I assume I will need to add platform specific code for this ?

[How to make a ListView with draggable items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123824/how-to-make-a-listview-with-draggable-items)

Additionally as seen by the below Xamarin forum post it seems that controls dont support drag/drop functionality therefore a custom renderer would need to be created but im not quite sure where to begin

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18114/do-the-xamarin-forms-controls-support-drag-drop-runtime-functionality

Comment: If anybody looking for xamarin android native solution for draggable list then you can check out here : http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2019/08/reorder-list-items-by-drag-and-drop-in.html

Answer (score 3):

For iOS, you can take advantage of the native `UITableView` control's reordering functionality. Create a custom renderer for a `ListView` that tells iOS that you'd like all rows to be movable. Have it update the source list's order to match the user's actions.

Start with a subclass.

```cs
public class EditListView : ListView { }
```

Then add a custom renderer that updates `ListView.ItemsSource` to reflect the changed order. This code assumes `ItemsSource` is a `List<ListItem>`, where `ListItem` has `Id` and `Name` properties of type string.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EditListView), typeof(EditListViewRenderer))]
public class EditListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            Control.Source = new TableViewSource((List<ListItem>)e.NewElement.ItemsSource);
            Control.Editing = true;
        }
    }

    class TableViewSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        readonly List<ListItem> items;

        public TableViewSource(List<ListItem> items) { this.items = items; }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var item = items[indexPath.Row];
            var cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, item.Id); // No recycling. If the list is big enough to need recycling, the user won't be very happy about reordering it by hand. :-)
            cell.TextLabel.Text = item.Name;
            return cell;
        }

        public override void MoveRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath sourceIndexPath, NSIndexPath destinationIndexPath)
        {
            int source = sourceIndexPath.Row, dest = destinationIndexPath.Row;
            var movedItem = items[source];
            items.RemoveAt(source);
            if (source > dest) --source;
            items.Insert(dest, movedItem);
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section) => items.Count;
        public override bool CanMoveRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) => true;
        public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) => true; // Only editable rows can be moved.
        public override bool ShouldIndentWhileEditing(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) => false;
        public override UITableViewCellEditingStyle EditingStyleForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) => UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out on your link, its not possible just using the supplied **Xamarin.Forms** controls.

You would therefore have to implement **Custom Renderers**, for each platform.

A great tutorial can be found on http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

At the very bottom of that page is a video that I really advise you to go through as it is very informative and should get you into writing your own **Custom Renderer** classes for **Android** and **iOS**.  The same principles apply to **Windows Phone** so if you wanted to target that also it shouldn't be too difficult also.

Comment: Thanks for the link, ill check out the tutorial and attempt an implementation

Comment: @ChadBonthuys - did you eventually get this working? It'd be great if you could post your solution :)

Comment: @JeremyThompson I experienced this problem a long time ago and Xamarin.Forms has come a long way since then. At the time I went for a simple implementation using a custom view cell with up/down arrows with a PropertyChangedEventHandler binded to the listview to refresh the item source on the event activation. Xamarin has released long press events and much better touch gestures since then so I'm sure this is now possible but I havent revisited it since. Here is reference to a link that may help you http://smartmobidevice.blogspot.co.za/2015/02/xamarinforms-listview-drag-and-drop-to.html