# Android save List<String>

Tags: android, list, save

Is there anyway I can save a List variable to the Androids phone internal or external memory? I know I can save primitive data, yet not sure about this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What method are you trying to use to save it?

Comment: Use SQLite :) a lightweight db

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes exactly you can only save primitives so you could something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

StringBuilder csvList = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : list){
      csvList.append(s);
      csvList.append(",");
}

sharedPreferencesEditor.put("myList", csvList.toString());
```

Then to create your `list` again you would:

```
String csvList = sharedPreferences.getString("myList");
String[] items = csvList.split(",");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++){
     list.add(items[i]);     
}
```

You could encapsulate this "serializing" into your own class wrapping a list to keep it nice and tidy. Also you could look at converting your `list` to `JSON`.

Comment: Make sure OP pays more attention if his list items contain commas.. I prefer the JSON method the best. It's so easy.

Comment: Gson is the easiest:  gson.toJson(OBJECT) is always what I do.

Comment: think you might want to add [i] in the line list.add(items) so it is list.add(items[i])

Comment: @SpiRail fixed thanks! .. only 9 years later :-)

Comment: Hey, I replied in 2018... that's 6 years... the last 3 years are all you.. 

Comment: haha a joint effort!  (and TIL you can paste emoji's here!)

Comment: can anyone tell me how can i update List<String> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72666876/how-to-use-notifydatasetchanged-without-an-adapter?noredirect=1#comment128358915_72666876

Answer (score 0):

I use ObjectOutputStream to save lists to storage.

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new  FileOutputStream(your_file));
oos.writeObject(your_list);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

That should do it. It works for me

Answer (score -2):

If you want to store/retrieve/delete some string value in your program, then `List` is better than `Array`. Here below I will show you that how to use it.

```
 // Declaring List Variable
 List<String> Mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

 // Adding item to List
 Mylist.add(list.size(), "MyStringValue");   //this will add string at the next index

 // Removing element form list
 Mylist.remove(list.size()-1);   //this will remove the top most element from List
```

Comment: He wants to save it on the device not only at application runtime