# How to update List<String> without adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

What I want is for every update I make in the firebase database to be reflected in the app too without completely restarting it

I previously used notifyDataStateChange in an app that contains a recyclerviewadapter, so when I made an update it would also be updated in the app

In this case, I don't have a recyclerview and I don't have an adapter, only a textview where I show the quotes when a button is pressed, so I don't know how I can update it.

Since I have used notifyDataStateChange in a previous app, I would like to use it again. If you have any other better solution, please let me know it isn't necessary to use notifyDataStateChange. I just want to update the data in my app.

**HomeActivity.java** // if u want to get the entier file refrence please let me know i will update the question

```
      TextView countTxt, quotesTxt, noAds;
      List<String> quotes_list;
      Model model;

       countTxt = findViewById(R.id.countText);
        quotesTxt = findViewById(R.id.quotesTextView);


databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes");
        model = new Model();
        quotes_list = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
                    if (model != null) {
                        quotes_list.add(model.getTitle());
                        position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                        Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());

                    }
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
                Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

**Model.java**

```
package com.example.philosophicalquotes;

public class Model {
    String title;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: `notifyDataStateChange` is not a magic stick its just a method which happens to be written in adapter to notify about the data set change . You can create a method to update the UI i.e change the data on screen . and call this method of firebase data change callback .

Comment: if i know everything why do i ask, i searched for how to Update List<String> but didnt find a good answer that solves  my issue

Comment: There's already `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)`.

Comment: yes but the data only change when i restart

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing changes at the Firebase Realtime Database, the data will update at the application if you are using `addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener)`.

You can refer to this link. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener#public-abstract-void-ondatachange-datasnapshot-snapshot

Refer to your question, you are using `addValueEventListener`. The value will update itself at the application.

I'm assuming this line code will print when you are creating new object.

```
Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.size().toString());
```