# How to convert a Vector to JSONArray?

Tags: java, vector, gson, arrays

I need to convert a `Vector<Vector<Float>>` to a `JSONArray`. Apart from iterating through the vector and creating the `JSONArray`, is there any simpler way to do this?

Someone told me to try gson.

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize it and deserialize it in the same method?  Your `json` string already holds your vector data as JSON.  By trying to get a JSONArray you're trying to get it back into Java objects (but with a different JSON library).  Why?  Why not just use `data`? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: My goal is to convert a Vector to a JSONObject. I searched around and it seemed like gson could help. Can you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Gson is for serializing Java objects into a JSON-formatted String.  JSONObject however is a Java object which is used when you want to take a JSON-formatted String and translate it *back* to Java objects.  It belongs to a completely different library.  When I asked what you're actually trying to accomplish, I meant at a higher level since your current goal seems flawed.  It doesn't make sense to go from one Java object type to another, using JSON as a pointless intermediary.  Do you have code that takes a JSONObject or something?  Are you trying to send JSON over a socket?  What is your goal?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to store a Vector in SharedPreferences of Android. There's a post in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android which takes a JSON object as a parameter to do this. I've already used Vectors throughout my code, so it's impractical to rewrite everything as a JSONArray. That's why I'm trying to convert a Vector to a JSONArray.

Comment: There's a method `saveJSONObject` there working by converting the `JSONObject` to string. So unless I'm badly mistaken, you can skip the useless JSON part and simply save the string as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` is just a key-value store.  What's stopping you from bypassing `JSONObject` completely, and just using something like this (Gson only)?

```
private static final Type DATA_TYPE = 
    new TypeToken<Vector<Vector<Float>>>() {}.getType();
```

**Storage:**

```
Vector<Vector<Float>> data = new Vector<Vector<Float>>();
data.add(new Vector<Float>());
data.get(0).add(3.0f);

String dataAsJson = new Gson().toJson(data, DATA_TYPE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("data", dataAsJson).commit();
```

**Retrieval:**

```
String dataAsJson = sharedPreferences.getString("data", "[]");
Vector<Vector<Float>> data = new Gson().fromJson(dataAsJson, DATA_TYPE);
```

*Disclaimer: I've never developed for Android.*