# REST entity filtering works only for single entity not for collection

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Im building a REST based application, and I wanted partial JSON filter response feature, for example, api.movies.com/movies/1?fields=title,year would return a JSON with only the title and production year of the movie with id=1.

After a lot of struggle i managed to find a very simple solution without a lot of dependencies that should work very well, and it does for the case above, but if the REST service returns a collection instead of a single entity it doesnt work, I debuged it, and i can filter each item of the collection, but on return i get a strange exception, so I trimed the code to the bone and left only this:

```
public class PartialResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Response filter");
        Object entity = responseContext.getEntity();
        responseContext.setEntity(entity);
}
```

And it still doesnt work, am I missing somthing or is this a bug on Java? The code above does work for a single entity but not for a colection, the REST service works fine, the problem is here in the interceptor.

The exception im getting is this:

```
StandardWrapperValve[com.app.myApp.service.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.app.myApp.service.ApplicationConfig threw exception
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.Vector, genericType=class java.util.Vector.
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
```

**EDIT:**

OK I managed to make it work, but needed to add yet another dependency, still annoys me that a set of a get throws a exception and setEntity() of ContainerResponseContect only works for a single entity but whatever.

```
responseContext.setEntity((new Gson()).toJson(collection));
```

That did the trick.

Comment: try with `text/json` maybe

Comment: It says you cannot convert a `Vector` instance into json, because you don't have a converter for that type. I cannot help further without any java knowledge...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954578/how-to-convert-a-vector-to-jsonarray
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/vector/convert-vector-to-object-array-example/

and I found even more stackoverflow links, so I think this is a duplicate

Comment: without the provider it works, and if the response from the service is a Vector (JAX-RS implementation not mine) how come I cant set the same Vector (that works!). This just doesnt make any sense. Whithout the provider it works. And no its not duplicated because what im trying to do is not convert Vector to JSON directly

Comment: Just look at the code, how can that code not work, im seting what im getting without doing anything in between, if i comment the set it works. It must be a dependency or something

Comment: I guess the `entity` contains a `Vector` instance and after setting it by `responseContext.setEntity(entity);` the system is trying to make a json representation of it. But I really don't know anything about java... Try to `dump` the `entity` variable, maybe it helps.

Comment: Hmm I don't think sending entities to the representation layer is a good choice, we usually send for example DTO-s, in which we can control what fields we send through, or by CQRS we don't work with entities by the read model. Maybe sending back a DTO (based on the properties of the entity) instead of an entity itself, would help. But that's just an opinion.