# how to set array in shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add an array or object to SharedPreferences on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android)

i created multiple alarm in my alarm clock using shared preferences now i want the alarm should ring at particular day of the week, for that i want an array which can save he day on which alarm should ring.
can anyone tell how to put array in shared preferences and how to retrive it again..?

```
SharedPreferences set=getSharedPreferences(MYPR, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed=set.edit();
            ed.putInt("Ahh", Ahh);
            ed.putInt("Amm",Amm);
            ed.putBoolean("en", true);
            ed.commit();
```

now i am putting alarm time and its property in shared pref. what is to be added to put array (day of week)also..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android

Comment: solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To write,**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put(1);
    jsonArray.put(2);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString());
    System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
    editor.commit();
```

**To Read,**

```
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key", "[]"));
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
             Log.d("your JSON Array", jsonArray2.getInt(i)+"");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Aah... I would say a perfect trick :)