# Store more than one value in Android app preferences using the same key

Tags: android, http-post, sharedpreferences

I'm not so sure on how can I store more than one value in shared preferences on an Android app using the same key.

What the app do is show a list and a button to add that item to favorites I want to store that numeric value to preferences and when the user go to the favorite list send all the stored favorites through http post in an array.

**EDIT:** I'm doing it this way but when I add a new value it overrides the last one, check implode method, I add the new value to the stored list empty or not it has to add the new value and preserve the last ones.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class FavoriteActivity {

    private static String FAVORITE_LIST = "FAV_LIST";
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
    private static Editor sharedPrefEditor;

    public static List<NameValuePair> getFavoriteList(Context context) {
        if (sharedPreference == null) {
            sharedPreference = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        }
        String storedList = sharedPreference.getString(FAVORITE_LIST, "");
        return explode(storedList);
    }

    public static void saveFavorite(String fav, Context context) {
        if (sharedPreference == null) {
            sharedPreference = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        }
        sharedPrefEditor = sharedPreference.edit();
        implode(getFavoriteList(context), fav, 1);
        sharedPrefEditor.putString(FAVORITE_LIST, fav);
        sharedPrefEditor.commit();
    }

    public static List<NameValuePair> explode(String string) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(string, ",");
        List<NameValuePair> v = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        for (; st.hasMoreTokens();) {
            v.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", st.nextToken()));
        }
        return v;
    }

    public static String implode(List<NameValuePair> list, String value,
            int mode) {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        switch (mode) {
        case 0:
            list.remove(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", value));
            break;
        case 1:
            list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", value));
            break;
        }
        boolean first = true;
        for (NameValuePair v : list) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                out.append(",");
            out.append(v.getValue());
        }
        return out.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. If you use the same key anywhere, it will overwrite the previous value.

Perhaps you could convert your values into an array and [store the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10815983/1069068), or maybe look into using an SQLite database, in which you can specify the keys in one column, and the corresponding value in another and then run a SELECT statement that selects all rows with the key in it.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking how can I achieve this, I can use putStringSet() but is only available on API level 11 or higher and my app need to be compatible with API level 8.

Comment: Hmmm, is efficient retrieve the array, add the new value and save the array again?.

Comment: @Shixons As efficient as any other SharedPrefs operation.

Answer (score 0):

Since api 11 you can put [StringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29). Another way is not possible.

Comment: Why i never can be first?! -_-

Comment: But it needs to me compatible with API 8 :(.

Comment: What about putString() like this: hello, my, name, is....
And them retrieve it and separate by commas?

Comment: I think in that way but... How can I delete values?.

Comment: Only replace value which you want delete with ""

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is the way I did it and works perfect, also it doesn't add any duplicates.

```
private static String FAVORITE_LIST = "FAV_LIST";
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
private static Editor sharedPrefEditor;

public static List<NameValuePair> getFavoriteList(Context context) {
    if (sharedPreference == null) {
        sharedPreference = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
    String storedList = sharedPreference.getString(FAVORITE_LIST, "");
    return explode(storedList);
}

public static void saveFavorite(String fav, Context context) {
    modifyFavorite(fav, context, 1);
}

public static void removeFavorite(String fav, Context context) {
    modifyFavorite(fav, context, 0);
}

private static void modifyFavorite(String fav, Context context, int mode) {
    if (sharedPreference == null) {
        sharedPreference = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
    sharedPrefEditor = sharedPreference.edit();
    String newList = implode(getFavoriteList(context), fav, mode);
    sharedPrefEditor.putString(FAVORITE_LIST, newList);
    sharedPrefEditor.commit();
}

private static List<NameValuePair> explode(String string) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(string, ",");
    List<NameValuePair> v = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (; st.hasMoreTokens();) {
        v.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", st.nextToken()));
    }
    return v;
}

private static String implode(List<NameValuePair> list, String value,
        int mode) {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    switch (mode) {
    case 0:
        list.remove(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", value));
        break;
    case 1:
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id[]", value));
        break;
    }
    boolean first = true;
    for (NameValuePair v : list) {
        if (out.lastIndexOf(v.getValue()) == -1) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                out.append(",");
            }
            out.append(v.getValue());
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```