# Save and check the radio button

Tags: android, radio-button, save

I'm facing a problem with radio buttons to save and check it again..

I have a radio group has four radiobuttons. For first attempt radiobutton in each group. When user clicks on any radiobutton and goes to next when user comeback from there, the selections made on these radiogroups/radiobuttons are gone.

How can I save/restore radiobutton selection state?

My Code..

```
private void LoadQuestions() {
            ques1.add("whats the name?");
            ques1.add("whats place?");
            ques1.add("whats the favourite?");
            ques1.add("whats the game?");
            ques1.add("whats the time?");

            answ1.add("A");answ1.add("B");answ1.add("C");answ1.add("D");
            answ1.add("MDU");answ1.add("MS");answ1.add("CHE");answ1.add("POND");
            answ1.add("1");answ1.add("2");answ1.add("3");answ1.add("4");
            answ1.add("VB");answ1.add("TENN");answ1.add("HOC");answ1.add("CRI");
            answ1.add("11");answ1.add("12");answ1.add("13");answ1.add("14");

            quetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
            quetxt.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(i));

            btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(0));
            btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(1));
            btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(2));
            btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(3));


            Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
            nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (i == ques1.size() -1) {
                        showAlert();
                }else{
                ++i;
                ++num;
                TextView quetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
                quetxt.setText("Q" + num + ")" +ques1.get(i));

                ++k;
                btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
                btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
                btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
                btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
                btn_practicerg.clearCheck();
                }
            }

            private void showAlert() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
               });

            Button previousbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accbtn);
            previousbtn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                --i;
                --num;
                TextView quetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
                quetxt.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(i));

                --k;
                btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
                btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
                btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
                btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
            }
            });



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`LoadQuestions()` should be written in your onCreate, so everytime you go back to the Activity, checkBox will keep their states.

If you want to keep these values for another instance of the ACtivitu, you should save the values in a Preference or in a database

Comment: turn the values into a String, for instance 0,1,1,0,1, save that to a preference, and parse it when needed.

Comment: Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android

Comment: I didn't understand, will you please work on im my code..i need to save and again i need to check that, it should not gone..please guide me..

Comment: The link I copied above is self explanatory.. In 2 minutes, you barely had time to read and to test, if you expect a full working code you are at the wrong place. Just tell us what you don't understand or what you have tried

Comment: I have tried for save the value its fine but from preference i can't able to check again that..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35464/discussion-between-waza-be-and-onemanarmy)