# Read 2d array values from file android

Tags: java, android, file, sharedpreferences, multidimensional-array

Hi I want my D2 int array to get its values from a file.  if the file not exist i want to create it and set all the values of the aray to 0. then when the values changes in the array i want to click my save button so the values in the file changes so the next time i open the app the array gets the new values from the begining.

I tried this code and now my app runs but after shutdown all values in "iss[][]" is equals to 0 again and not the values i saved.

```
int[][] iss = new int [11][11];
String name;


 public void readFile2(String fileName) {
     SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

     String savedString = prefs.getString(fileName, "");
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[0][i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString1 = prefs.getString(fileName + "1", "");
     StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(savedString1, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[1][i] = Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString2 = prefs.getString(fileName + "2", "");
     StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(savedString2, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) { 
         while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[2][i] = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString3 = prefs.getString(fileName + "3", "");
     StringTokenizer st3 = new StringTokenizer(savedString3, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st3.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[3][i] = Integer.parseInt(st3.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString4 = prefs.getString(fileName + "4", "");
     StringTokenizer st4 = new StringTokenizer(savedString4, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st4.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[4][i] = Integer.parseInt(st4.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString5 = prefs.getString(fileName + "5", "");
     StringTokenizer st5 = new StringTokenizer(savedString5, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st5.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[5][i] = Integer.parseInt(st5.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString6 = prefs.getString(fileName + "6", "");
     StringTokenizer st6 = new StringTokenizer(savedString6, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st6.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[6][i] = Integer.parseInt(st6.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString7 = prefs.getString(fileName + "7", "");
     StringTokenizer st7 = new StringTokenizer(savedString7, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st7.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[7][i] = Integer.parseInt(st7.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString8 = prefs.getString(fileName + "8", "");
     StringTokenizer st8 = new StringTokenizer(savedString8, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st8.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[8][i] = Integer.parseInt(st8.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString9 = prefs.getString(fileName + "9", "");
     StringTokenizer st9 = new StringTokenizer(savedString9, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st9.hasMoreTokens()) { 
         iss[9][i] = Integer.parseInt(st9.nextToken());
         }
     }

     String savedString10 = prefs.getString(fileName + "10", "");
     StringTokenizer st10 = new StringTokenizer(savedString10, ",");
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         while (st10.hasMoreTokens()) {
         iss[10][i] = Integer.parseInt(st10.nextToken());
     }
     }
     }

 public void firstfile(){
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     fritis = extras.getIntArray("friti");//friti is value from spinner

     if((fritis[0] == 0) && (fritis[1]== 10)){
            String fileName = "all";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if((fritis[0] == 0) && (fritis[1]== 0)){
            String fileName = "cer";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 1){
            String fileName = "one";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 2){
            String fileName = "two";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 3){
            String fileName = "three";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 4){
            String fileName = "four";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 5){
            String fileName = "five";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 6){
            String fileName = "six";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 7){
            String fileName = "seven";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 8){
            String fileName = "eight";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 9){
            String fileName = "nine";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }
        else if(fritis[0] == 10){
            String fileName = "ten";
            name=fileName;

            readFile2(fileName);
        }


 }

            public void save_file(){//saves iss[][]

    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str.append(iss[0][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name, str.toString());

    StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str1.append(iss[1][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"1", str1.toString());

    StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str2.append(iss[2][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"2", str2.toString());

    StringBuilder str3 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str3.append(iss[3][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"3", str3.toString());

    StringBuilder str4 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str4.append(iss[4][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"4", str4.toString());

    StringBuilder str5 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str5.append(iss[5][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"5", str5.toString());

    StringBuilder str6 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str6.append(iss[6][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"6", str6.toString());

    StringBuilder str7 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str7.append(iss[7][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"7", str7.toString());

    StringBuilder str8 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str8.append(iss[8][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"8", str8.toString());

    StringBuilder str9 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str9.append(iss[9][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"9", str9.toString());

    StringBuilder str10 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        str10.append(iss[10][i]).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString(name+"10", str10.toString());


}
```

/ thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the SharedPreferences mechanism in Android for this.  Check this question for some examples:

[Is it possible to add an array or object to SharedPreferences on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android)

Comment: I tried but i didn't get it to work. I have updated to the new the code now.