# Android: Best technique to keep data, among Activities, consistent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, consistency

The user of my application will be able to change(add,edit,delete) the following data:

- name
- number1
- number2
- number3

All those data are parallel. For example:

> George 200 100 50
>
> Andreas 450 205 190
>
> John 800 230 180

The user will be able to change the first three (name, time1, time2) from an Activity. And the last one (time3) from another Activity.

Upon change on those data a service would like to know about the changes immediately.

The solutions I am aware of are:

1. Storing the arrays using shared preferences ([Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android)) but this would be too time consuming for my application as I may have up to (maximum) 200 data entries. (so `200x4 data to store`).
2. Upon change on the tables I can keep my data consistent by storing them in a database and sending a broadcast to my service with (putExtra) the new data. The service will locally update those arrays. The problem with this solution is that each time I want to make a change on the data I have to change my database too, which is time consuming.

Are there any other solutions?

Is any of the above a good solution for my problem?

Comment: By database I mean ContentProvider. Is it the best solution though?

Comment: ContentProvider != database so it doesnt have to be slow

Comment: ok, thanks. I guess I ContentProvider is a good solution then. Should I delete the question? I think it's fail.

Comment: its ok, maybe someone will provide a better solution/