# How to add a Boolean Array in Shared preferences in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to store a Boolean array in Shared preferences ,and i want to access the array elements later. Can anybody help me ?.Thanks in advnc.

Comment: There is another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Store your array

```
public boolean storeArray(Boolean[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   

    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
        editor.putBoolean(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]); 

    return editor.commit();  
}
```

Load your array

```
public Boolean[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  

    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    Boolean array[] = new Boolean[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getBoolean(arrayName + "_" + i, false);  

    return array;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Store your array globally set checkbox value

```
 public boolean setCheckboxarray(Context mContext,Boolean[] array) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(CHECKBOXARRAY, array.length);

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        editor.putBoolean(CHECKBOXARRAY + i, array[i]);

    return editor.commit();
}
```

Load your array globally get checkbox value

```
public Boolean[] getCheckboxarray(Context mContext) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    int size = prefs.getInt(CHECKBOXARRAY, 0);
    Boolean array[] = new Boolean[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        array[i] = prefs.getBoolean(CHECKBOXARRAY+ i, false);

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store ArrayList Globally in sharedpreferences using checkbox.

```
 public boolean saveCheckboxarray(Context mContext, ArrayList<Boolean> array) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(CHECKBOXARRAY, array.size());

    for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
        editor.putBoolean(CHECKBOXARRAY + i,array.get(i));

    return editor.commit();
}
```

Load ArrayList Globally in sharedpreferences Status.

```
public ArrayList<Boolean> getCheckboxarray(Context mContext) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    int size = prefs.getInt(CHECKBOXARRAY, 0);
    ArrayList<Boolean> getArray=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        getArray.add(i,prefs.getBoolean(CHECKBOXARRAY + i, false));

    return getArray;
}
```