# set visibility for 5 textview at same time : android

Tags: android

i have two page(main activity page and favorites page),i working on the favorites page , i want when the user clicked on my favorite button ,that page will be showed on another activity that called favorites page. so i can catch page that user clicked and can transfer that value to another activity(means favorites page) with SharedPreferences, but in favorites page i can set visibility my gone textview. below code worked for me but only one textview only visible for me , for example when btn1 in main activity textview1 in favorites page is visible but when i click on btn2 in main activity the textview2 in favorites is visible but textview1 is no showed  and only one textview showed to me, anybody can help me? i want all textview that user clicked be visible Together.

my cod is :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    int score = pref.getInt("score", 0);

    List<Boolean> listtt=new ArrayList<Boolean>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[5]));
    Collections.fill(listtt, new Boolean(false));


    switch (score) {

    case 99:
        if(score == 99){
            pos=99;
            tv_favoritetittle.setText("Nothing");

        }
        break;

    case 100:
        if(score == 100){
            listtt.set(0, true);
            pos=100;
        }
        break;
case 101:
    if(score == 101){
        listtt.set(1, true);
        pos=101;
    }
        break;
case 102:
    if(score == 102){
        listtt.set(2, true);
        pos=102;
    }
    break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

and my called function to set visibility of textview:

```
public void setvisibility(int id){

if(id==100){
    tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else {tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

if(id==101){
    tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else {tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to call the setvisibility method somewhere.

Second, and more important, you have to notice, that the values that you set into your listtt are never saved anywhere. They won't exist anymore after going to another activity, if you don't save them (manually)!

You can do that e.g. by saving it to the sharedPreferences:

In your onDestroy method iterate through your listtt and put all the values to the sharedPreferences via a SharedPreferences.Editor.

Comment: From your code I'd suggest saving it to the sharedpreferences.

Comment: i stored in arrayelist with this command :  listtt.set(1, true);

Comment: yes, but this arraylist isn't saved anywhere! You have to put it's values somewhere, to be able to read them, when you need them!

Comment: how i can do it ? (means saved arraylist) and access it later? tnx

Comment: i found it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159926/how-to-add-a-boolean-array-in-shared-preferences-in-android but how can i use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

'textView.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE)'

for all the textViews back to back it will appear that they come on at the same time to the user. Do the same for gone.

Comment: You need to send an intent to another class and use this method in the oncreate of that class

Comment: Or if you want to stay in that class just do it in the buttons on click listener

Comment: i user sharedprefrences and success retreive my value , my problem in show textview together

Comment: So setting the visibility for each one one by one is not working? Are you sure you defined the textViews.

Comment: its work on bye one, but i want pervious textview stay visible but it not