# Storing top 5 scores in a shared preference failing

Tags: java, android

Im trying to store the top 5 high scores inside a `sharedpreference` instead of an `sqlite` database. So I looked around and found two methods (saveArray and loadArray) from a stack post here ( [Is it possible to add an array or object to SharedPreferences on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android) )

Anyway when I try and add in a value to the array I get an `arrayoutofbounds` error. `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0;index=0`

Because the user will not start with values in the array I'm trying to determine if the array has a value at position ***i***, If not I am trying to insert the score that was passed into the array at that position. But it won't work and I'm not sure why?

So essentially if `highscores[i] != null` then I'll go and check to see if `highscores[i] < intScore`, if `highscores is < intScore` then I will replace it with the passed score in the constructor.

```
String[] highscores = new String[5];

public void editHighscores(String score){
    int intScore = Integer.parseInt(score);


    highscores = loadArray("highscores",this.getApplicationContext());

    // Checks to see if index is empty
    for(int i=0;i<5; i++){
        if(highscores[i] == null){
            highscores[i] = score;
        } else{
            if(Integer.parseInt(highscores[i]) < intScore){
                highscores[i] = score;
            }
        }

        Log.d("index - " + i, "Value = " + highscores[i]);
    }
    // Save the array
    saveArray(highscores, "highscores", this.getApplicationContext());




}
public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("highscoresPref", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
        editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);  
    return editor.commit();  
} 

public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("highscoresPref", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    String array[] = new String[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);  
    return array;  
}
```

Comment: I think you need to change **int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);**  to **int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 5);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `loadArray()` method, `size` defaults to 0. On your first run, there won't be any saved preference, so the `size` is 0, and this is what you're using to dimension the array.

Since you're checking for null values in the `editHighscores()` method, you don't need to track the size. You've already decided how big the array should be: 5.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So I can just take out the size altogether from the loadArray() method?

Comment: What I did was replace the `size variable` in the `loadArray()` method with a static value of 5. Instead of having it statically declared I could simply add another argument to the constructor.

Comment: I would just make it a constant: `private static final int HIGH_SCORE_COUNT = 5;`. Then you only have to change that one value should you ever decide to track, say, the top ten scores.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
String[] highscores = new String[5];

  public void editHighscores(String score){
int intScore = Integer.parseInt(score);


highscores = loadArray("highscores",this.getApplicationContext());

 if(highscores!=null && highscroes.length>0)
     {
    // Checks to see if index is empty
      for(int i=0;i<5; i++){
       if(highscores[i] == null){
           highscores[i] = score;
       } else{
        if(Integer.parseInt(highscores[i]) < intScore){
            highscores[i] = score;
        }
    }

    Log.d("index - " + i, "Value = " + highscores[i]);
}
// Save the array
saveArray(highscores, "highscores", this.getApplicationContext());


   }

  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just prevent any data from ever being saved into the array? Because I'm starting with an empty shared preference, meaning it will always be null or the length will always be 0 unless I can access that for loop to insert data into the array.

Comment: No..because..you are editing saved list...first time you will save list using saveArray..then you will call edit..right?

Answer (score 0):

Initially `int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);` will return size `0` as array size is not stored.

So, `loadArray` method will `return` `empty Array`..

In your `editHighscores` method you are trying to insert score on empty array which will produce `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So as work around Replace `int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);` 
with `int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 5);`