# Save ArrayList that contains duplicate values with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList that contains Some Dates.
I want to save it to user's storage to use it later.
here's the code i've tried:

```
ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add("1 شهریور 1395");
dates.add("1 شهریور 1395");
dates.add("2 شهریور 1395");
dates.add("2 شهریور 1395");
SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
preferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = preferences.edit();
Set<String> dateSet = new Set(dates);
editor.putStringSet(dateSet);
```

but when i call `dateSet.size()` well it's normal that it returns 2... not 4.
how can i save my `dates` without reducing it's size?

Comment: @Andy then how can i save the arraylist in `sharedPreferences` ?

Comment: search your comment content on google , you will find many helpful answers,good luck

Comment: Your dates are strings.  Your strings are 1, 1, 2, 2.  When things are added to a Set, a set calls the .equals method to see if the object is already in the set.  That is why the list has 4 entries and the Set only has 2: There are two 1's and two 2's making the Set filter a 1 and a 2 out upon insertion.

Comment: @Sandy this is the Actual values in my project.

Comment: @Pavneet i have tried a lot... found nothing. All was how to remove not ignore removing duplicate values.

Comment: @PavneetSingh I don't think you can get around it unless you change the list's values.  A Set does not allow duplicate values in it, and duplicates are determined by the .equals method.

Comment: @SandySimonton the values are token from a html source code using Jsoup library. not my decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `putString()`

> Set a String value in the preferences editor, to be written back once commit() or apply() are called.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `putStringSet()`. Serialize the array in some format such as JSON or csv and do `putString()` instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287418/6865211

Comment: Solution was to Serialize the array in JSON and use `putString()` . thanks.